# Bulk export RDF from fuseki

Tags: export, fuseki

I am using fuseki 1.0,we want to export the RDF data from fuseki 1.0.we want the bulk export from fuseki 1.0 to import into marklogic.what are all the ways available for bulk export from fuseki 1.0?what are all the tools available for bulk RDF export?How to export?Please clarify.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you wish to import into Marklogic as RDF.

Your basic options are SPARQL [CONSTRUCT](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#construct) queries or a [GET](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-http-rdf-update/#http-get) using the SPARQL Graph Store HTTP Protocol. How complicated this is depends on whether you are using named graphs in your Fuseki store and want to preserve them when importing into Marklogic. If you choose to use the HTTP option Fuseki includes helper scripts, see the SPARQL over HTTP section of the documentation or simply try running the s-get script.

Comment: Thanks chrisis.. we have the option of HTTP protocol to get the data.But we have more than 20GB data that need to export in RDF type.Other than HTTP option,do we have any tool to export?

Comment: From memory I don't think Fuseki 1 had a backup option. You could just upgrade to Fuseki 2 and use its backup option. It backs up NQuads gzipped. I don't know Marklogic but I'd be surprised if it can't import NQuads directly from the compressed file.

Comment: Thanks crisis,we upgraded and tried for the backup from version fuseki 2.As we have large data,it throw error  as "ObjectFileStorage.read and impossibly large object".how to solve this?and want to know how we see the  relationship in fuseki data's  lik SQL table,row,,columns?